# Search for the next line that does not match a pattern

Tags: search

The `/` command moves to the next occurrence of a pattern.  But how do I move to the next line in which a pattern does *not* appear?

Comment: You might have a look [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_for_lines_not_containing_pattern).

Comment: ... which gives something like `/\v^((pattern)@!.)*$`

Answer (score 6):

Recent Vims come with the [LogiPat plugin](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1290). With that, you can simply do

```
:LogiPat !"foo"
```

and it will jump to the next line, not containting your pattern. To see the pattern, you can type

```
:echo @/
```

which should show something like `^\%(\%(foo\)\@!.\)*$`

Comment: TIL `:LogiPat` :)

Comment: Beware however that the patterns produced by `LogiPat` are not always perfect (cf. `:help logipat-caveat`).  "Negating" regexps is always tricky, and `LogiPat` is not a silver bullet.

Comment: @SatoKatsura True